# Unsupported or misplaced expression in Julia Dict

Tags: dictionary, julia

I tried to run this command

```
dict = Dict("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4, "e" => 5)
```

in Julia 0.3.2 (via https://try.jupyter.org/) and got this error:

```
unsupported or misplaced expression =>
while loading In[1], in expression starting on line 1
```

I understand from [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.Dict) that this notation for dicts should be ok.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is slightly different in 0.3:

```
x= Dict({"a"=>5})
```

Note the curly brackets!

Whereas the code you wrote is 0.4 syntax. You can check the documents by changing the version number.

Just for reference the 0.4 syntax is:

```
 x=Dict("a"=>5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here who are using Julia 1.0.0, note that the OP's code now works:

```
julia> dict = Dict("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4, "e" => 5)
Dict{String,Int64} with 5 entries:
  "c" => 3
  "e" => 5
  "b" => 2
  "a" => 1
  "d" => 4

julia> VERSION
v"1.0.0"
```

An example from the Julia 1.0.0 [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.Dict) is below:

> Alternatively, a sequence of pair arguments may be passed.

```
julia> Dict("A"=>1, "B"=>2)
Dict{String,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "B" => 2
  "A" => 1
```